# android studio doesn't show genymotion logs after connecting device(Huawei Y520)

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion, android-logcat

I have problem with that type. Logs works fine with Genymotion, but if I change genymotion device to android device (Huawei Y520) and then again change device to Genymotion logs doesn't appear.

Comment: I haven't worked with Genymotion emulators but I'm pretty sure you can select the device you're checking logs for in the log cat. Make sure you have your emulator selected and not your huawei device. :)

Comment: @Razgriz, I checked it is many times.

Comment: @DaurenChapaev: Was this issue solved? If so how?

Comment: @SanjanaNair no, I can not solve it.